# how to import alfresco metadata and content in solr 6

Tags: json, solr, alfresco, dih

I'm new to `solr` and `alfresco` and i need to create `solr 6` index importing metadata and content from alfresco. You may say that `alfresco` has already a bulk `solr 4` with its own index but i cannot touch it and at the moment it has no fields in it except for id and version, so it's not usefull.

I managed to create documents in index by importing from oracle db which i will use to integrate entities imported eventually from `alfresco`.

Tried to use alfresco api which return json as response but, even if the `DIH` documentation says betweeen goals that "Make it possible to plugin any kind of datasource `(ftp,scp etc)` and any other format of user choice `(JSON,csv etc)`", I did not find anything about it

Anyone faced already this problem and how it solved it?
Hope in your suggestions and maybe different approaches.

Comment: Your problem is how to fetch documents already in Alfresco, so you can index them in your own SOLR - in addition to the one already available with Alfresco installation - am I following you?

Comment: that's right. What i really don't understand is how the bundle solr creates the index basing on alfresco document...Eventually i would like to replicate the mechanism. At the moment i'm thinking of extending the URLDataSource or  creating a new Processor for processing json. Thanks

Comment: In addition to Jeff Pots answer below, you can use the same principle Alfresco does at the moment and pull the changes periodically to the SOLR. A nice starting point: http://alfresco.blog.redpill-linpro.com/2015/04/30/how-to-debug-solr-exceptionswarnings-for-alfresco-part-2/

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to essentially send information from Alfresco to your own Solr 6 install. You do not want to touch the embedded Solr server that comes with Alfresco because you will probably break something critical to Alfresco functioning properly.

You may want to take a look at this project: https://manifoldcf.apache.org. It can be used to pump data from Alfresco to Solr.

Comment: I already knew manifoldcf but found it difficult to configure it. So i would prefer to avoid it. At the moment i'm creating a custom datasource and JsonProcessor for dataimport. I'll post them if i succeed to make them work.

Comment: At the moment i created a jar with my new Datasource and i'm struggling to understand where to put it in order to be foung by jetty/solr classloader. Any  hints? The only way at the moment was to put the single class into dataimporthandler.jar but at the first depencency that calls, it fails.

Comment: Hello,

for some reasons stackoverflow decided i cannot post any answer. I managed to create a customDataSource that invokes a rest service, gets the response in json, converts in xml and then, configuring the mapping via xpathProcessor, should work.